# How to make an offline web app to store JSON file with Image

Tags: json, html, offline, offline-caching

I'm developing a simple application, I'm retrieving news from Server using JSON, I want to keep my app running offline, which I find really hard to do, what kind of tool I should use,

I was thinking about HTML 5 cache, it doesn't help a lot as long as I have an image to store. as I do know

here is a structure of my son file :

```js
"idNews": "586090487045578752",
"nbView": 0,
"title": "RT @equipedefrance: France-Canada, c'est ce soir 21h en direct sur @D17 ! ",
"newsAuthor": "@EAG_Officiel via Twitter",
"authorLogo": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000303320750\/1278a6515de5ddf3a61903f4e057733e_normal.png",
"type": 2,
"description": "RT @equipedefrance: France-Canada, c'est ce soir 21h en direct sur @D17 ! http:\/\/t.co\/qnzkbOWgSK Billetterie: http:\/\/t.co\/ctUdTfi4Ev #FRACA…",
"shortDescription": "",
"pubDate": "2015-04-09 08:57:15",
"expirationDate": "2015-10-09 11:18:13",
"image": "http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/uQcwAgT6K38\/0.jpg",
"imageAuthor": "En Avant de Guingamp",
"video": "uQcwAgT6K38",
"videoType": "youtube",
"idCommunity": 30898,
"messageCount": 0,
"language": "fr",
```

I just need some Ideas, or any online examples

Comment: u came up with a solution?

Comment: Hello there ! I used Angular Cache system I hope that will help you